# Pasar elementos de un Listbox a una matriz bidimensional en C#

Tags: c#, array

Quiero calcular el promedio de esta matriz pero solo clases, tomando como base esta matriz:

```
2 4 4 0 0 
1 3 5 5 5
1 5 3 2 4
2 6 2 1 3
2 5 3 0 1
```

La primera columna indica el numero de la clase que pertenece la fila, la primera fila solo indica el numero de clases, el numero de objetos y el numero de atributos.

Es decir:

```
2 4 4 0 0 //matriz[0,0] numero de clases, matriz[0,1] numero de objetos, matriz[0,2] numero de atributos
1 3 5 5 5 //matriz[1,0] clase a la que pertenece la fila osea clase 1
1 5 3 2 4 //matriz[2,0] clase a la que pertenece la fila osea clase 1
2 6 2 1 3 //matriz[3,0] clase a la que pertenece la fila osea clase 2
2 5 3 0 1 //matriz[4,0] clase a la que pertenece la fila osea clase 2
```

En pocas palabras quiero el promedio de cada clase por columna.

Este es mi código pero solo saca el promedio de la matriz completa.

```
 int x = showdata.Items.Count;
        int y = showdata.Items[0].ToString().Split().Count();
        matriz = new Int32[x, y];
        contCol = new Int32[x];

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matriz[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(showdata.Items[i].ToString().Split()[j]);
            }
        }

        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(cont);

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < x; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    contCol[cont] = matriz[j, i];



                    listBox2.Items.Add(contCol[cont]);

                }


            }

            cont++;
        }


        int f = listBox2.Items.Count;
        contCol = new Int32[f];

        for (int i = 0; i < contCol.GetLength(0); i++)
            contCol[i] = Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.Items[i].ToString());



        cont = 0;
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(contCol[0]);
        for (int i=0;i<y;i++)
        {

            suma = 0;
            if (contCol[cont] == i)
            {

                if (i > 0)
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
                    {
                        if (contCol[cont] == j)
                        {
                            if (j > 0)
                                suma = suma + matriz[j, i];
                        }

                    }
                }
                promedio = (suma / (x - 1));
                if (promedio != 0)
                    listcentroide.Items.Add(promedio);

            }
        }
```

Comment: En la primer línea declaras `i=0; i<y; i++`, ¿de dónde sale `y` y en qué valor tiene?

Comment: Me quedó una duda, ¿el promedio va a incluir el identificador de la clase? Podrías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/109501/edit) tu pregunta poniendo el resultado esperado ;)

Comment: Hola, ya edite el codigo "y" sale del tamaño de la matriz y no el promedio no incluye el identificador de la clase ni la primera fila

Answer (score 1):

Como sugiere Flxtr en un comentario, incluir en tu pregunta el resultado esperado ayuda a encontrar una respuesta, no sólo a los que puedan responder sino a ti mismo.

La mejor forma de hacer esto es usando tests unitarios. Básicamente, un test unitario es un código que ejercita el algoritmo que quieres desarrollar y comprueba que su resultado es el esperado. [Aquí puedes encontrar más información sobre el tema.](https://www.google.es/search?q=escribir%20nunit%20tests)

He escrito el siguiente test, espero que cumpla con lo que buscas. Obtiene un diccionario cuya clave es el número de columna y su valor otro diccionario, cuya clave es la clase y su valor el promedio. Así, encontrar el promedio en la columna x para la clase y será `resultado[x][y]`:

```
public void TestObtenerPromediosPorClasePorColumna()
{
    int[,] matriz = {
        {2, 4, 4, 0, 0},
        {1, 3, 5, 5, 5},
        {1, 5, 3, 2, 4},
        {2, 6, 2, 1, 3},
        {2, 5, 3, 0, 1}
    };

    var resultado = ObtenerPromedios(matriz);

    var promedioColumna1Clase1 = resultado[1][1];
    Assert.AreEqual(4.0, promedioColumna1Clase1);
    var promedioColumna1Clase2 = resultado[1][2];
    Assert.AreEqual(5.5, promedioColumna1Clase2);
    var promedioColumna2Clase1 = resultado[2][1];
    Assert.AreEqual(4.0, promedioColumna2Clase1);
    var promedioColumna2Clase2 = resultado[2][2];
    Assert.AreEqual(2.5, promedioColumna2Clase2);
}
```

Una vez establecido el objetivo, podemos escribir el algoritmo. Al hacerlo, es altamente recomendable utilizar variables con nombres explicativos, como `numeroDeFilas` o `promediosPorClase`. Te dejo aquí el algoritmo que obtiene el resultado esperado:

```
private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>> ObtenerPromedios(int[,] matriz)
{
    var resultado = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, double>>();

    int numeroDeFilas = matriz.GetLength(0);
    int numeroDeColumnas = matriz.GetLength(1);

    for (int ncol = 0; ncol < numeroDeColumnas; ncol++)
    {
        var valoresPorClase = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

        for (int nfila = 1; nfila < numeroDeFilas; nfila++)
        {
            int valor = matriz[nfila, ncol];
            int clase = matriz[nfila, 0];

            if (!valoresPorClase.ContainsKey(clase))
            {
                valoresPorClase.Add(clase, new List<int>());
            }

            valoresPorClase[clase].Add(valor);
        }

        var promediosPorClase = new Dictionary<int, double>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> valores in valoresPorClase)
        {
            int clase = valores.Key;
            double promedio = valores.Value.Average();
            promediosPorClase.Add(clase, promedio);
        }

        resultado.Add(ncol, promediosPorClase);
    }

    return resultado;
}
```